# A possible mistake in a textbook about characterization of $\det(A+B)=0$ for $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

If A and B are square matrices or order 2, then $\det(A + B) = 0$ is possible only when

1. $\det (A) = 0$ or $\det (B) = 0$
2. $\det (A) + \det (B)  = 0$
3. $\det (A) = 0$ and $\det (B) = 0$
4. $A + B = 0$

Option D is said to be correct. But my doubt is:-

Suppose A = \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\2&6\end{bmatrix} and B = \begin{bmatrix}0&3\\4&2\end{bmatrix}
Here the det (A+B) = 0. But none of the options are satisfied, not even the correct one. Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net So it is possible that none of the options are correct.

Comment: Yes! Error can exist in exercises or books! Just for the sake of clarity, the matrices are supposed to have real entries?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes only real entries

Comment: Do you have a link to the question? In your copy there might be a typo. For example there is no option $D$ which you are referring to. Usually the last option is *None of the above*.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  It's not a typo. I removed the A, B, C, D options so  that they don't confuse with the matrix. I replaced it with 1, 2, 3,4. So, D option is 4. And no link to the question. It's from a book

Comment: Yes, I assume that you are right. But it is impossible to verify this without a scan of the book pages or a link. Errors occur on both sides frequently.